# Rainbow clarification

Tags: reflection, refraction

I've been thinking about rainbows and I understand in basic terms the wave length, light refraction and reflection as well as the principle that gives us the curved light array we see. My question is, theoretically IF we could observe the specific rain drops that are creating a rainbow at a position perpendicular to the rain drops that reflect back to a viewer, what shape would those rain drops show up as? I had it in my head after doing a sketch or two that the drops would arch away from the rainbow viewer as the raindrops in play got further away from the earths surface due to the fairly specific angles of reflection required. Your thoughts?

Comment: What does this mean? - "the specific rain drops that are creating a rainbow at a position perpendicular to the rain drops that reflect back to a viewer".

Comment: I saw once rainbows from an airplane. They were in several concentric circles opposite to the sun.

Comment: @safesphere are you sure it was a rainbow?  https://www.theguardian.com/science/2014/oct/29/fly-over-rainbow-break-laws-physics. I think you saw a "glory", there's an answer on this site somewhere about this.

Comment: The drops are _all the same shape_.  The light leaving each drop forms concentric cones of different colors.  When you look at a rainbow, the red band comes from all of the drops in whose red cone you are standing, and the same goes for each other color.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#Explanation

Comment: @Countto10: The Guardian, seriously? ;) Well, they ain't wron, if you real on: "There could be situations when a rainbow appears briefly to one side or below a plane if the angles all add up right but that is not the case here." Except for the "briefly" part, because it wasn't brief, but lasted for many minutes. I'll check if I took any photos. They are correct it's rare. I've flown the same 2-hour route 300 times, but the right angles and the right clouds came together only once. They are correct, it's on the side and below, not like the photo, but a full circle rainbows one inside the other.

Comment: @safesphere ok, point taken (again:),  possibly I could could have chosen a better source, but it had nice pictures... But I am also wrong about thinking you could not see a rainbow from an aircraft, just not a good day for me, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Rainbows appear to originate from a frustum of a hollow cone $ (A, B) $ as in handsketch.(sorry about poor quality). If you are looking up from ground only an arc is visible. From an aircraft you see concentric vibgyor  rain circles  in the clouds below whose center is the shadow of plane you are traveling  in.
[image: RainDrops in Coud]

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=raining+circle&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CUOvArj4niTQIkCLlUkSMdDLJlnOPBwjRukPnocyupV4mOE2ce0DMcZGkJ9JjgNF3dNMMH5vLB0_18WMlUNfVsdPXvY741XL0qq0JKhIJi5VJEjHQyyYRGLn8LUoWlsgqEglZzjwcI0bpDxEqFVrP2wPgWioSCZ6HMrqVeJjhEVBQymtEISCXKhIJNnHtAzHGRpARk1Eg7aSkyiMqEgmfSY4DRd3TTBFYVKnrYY0geCoSCTB-bywdP_1FjER5G12UYUJuKKhIJJVDX1bHT170RQa_13ZAgmimQqEgmO-NVy9KqtCRE8d6DaTgI_1Fw%3D%3D&tbo=u&ved=0ahUKEwiekNmD5qfWAhWHuo8KHSt0Ao8QuIIBCCM#imgdii=2VdKLVar7W4pvM:&imgrc=Niczn21_ifrgPM:

Small colorful rings as they appear from a plane.

Comment: +1: The shadow of the plane was indeed in the center as expected when I saw a rainbow from an airplane as I mentioned in the comments above. It's very rare, only saw it once in 10 years and 300 flights. A rainbow is easy to create though with a sprinkler in your hand. Stand back to the sun and mist water around your shadow. I do it for fun every time I water my lawn :)

Comment: Me too. Actually up from a tall post and a pond of fountains we could get colorful "rain-rings", but yet to try it out.